# Discord.py - How to make the "client" variable supportive with "message"?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make my bot reply when someone reacts to a message.
Here is my code. ->

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = reaction.message.channel
    await client.send_message(channel, '{} has added {} to the message {}',format(user.name, reaction.emoji, reaction.message.content))
```

Can anyone tell me why my`await client.send_message` is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are using code for an older version of the library? `send` is a method of `Channel`, not `Client`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = reaction.message.channel
    await channel.send('{} has added {} to the message {}'.format(
        user.name, reaction.emoji, reaction.message.content
    ))
```

Should work.